# CAS - Logout not working properly

Tags: java, xml, logout, cas

My Java Web Application is called within a platform with an user already logged into CAS. This platform has a LOGOUT button.
When my application is reached for the first time in a session, the current user is correct. But if user clicks on LOGOUT and he signs in with a different account, when my app is reached again the current user is the first one.So, I think that logout isn't working properly.

My web.xml is the following:

```js
<filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
 <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>https://casServer/login</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>serverName</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8082</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
        
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>https:/casServer/cas/</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>serverName</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8082</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>    
        <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I also faced same issue when I was doing this and still I didn't find any solution for this but if you want then I can give you a alternative idea where this issue will fix.

Comment: Can you please show your security-config.xml

Comment: Cas server is remote.

Comment: @MickeyPatel what is your alternative idea?

Comment: Before that tell me one thing are you using spring security here specially while logging out??

Comment: @MickeyPatel no I'm not.

Comment: My app doesn't use spring